# Load a text file with values into a tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tuples, file-handling

I have text file `file.txt` with values like this:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
```

What I want is a tuple like this in Python 3:

```
my_tuple = ('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5')
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    my_tuple=tuple(line.strip('\n') for line in f)

print(my_tuple)
# ('word1','word2','word3','word4','word5')
```

Comment: Choosing this as the accepted answer because the other one which is simpler without the for loop ends up creating a empty string item at the end of the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
     tup = tuple(f.read().split('\n'))

tup
('word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `list` and then convert it into a `tuple`.

```
import os.path
text_file = open("file.txt", encoding="utf8")
my_list = []

for line in text_file:     
    my_list.append(line)

my_tuple = tuple(my_list)
print(my_tuple)
print(type(my_tuple))
```